# How do I route my domain name to my server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I am currently hosting my website on amazon elasticbeanstalk and I purchased a domain from namecheap.com then I followed the steps [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html). On AWS route 53 I created a hosted zone and an Alias record then on my namecheap account I selected custom DNS as my DNS servers and inputted the values I got from AWS route 53. Now after 24 hours I can access my website from www.domain.com but not from domain.com. I opened up a terminal and I pinged domain.com it says "unknown host domain.com" but pinging www.domain.com works. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to create an another `Record Set` with empty name i.e. leave the name field blank and provide the value same as www.yourdomain.com (your IP address).

Please do note that both the values on `WWW` and `non-www` should be the same.

Hope this would solve your problem!

Comment: Glad to know, I have helped.Thanks!